# Why is is_trivially_copyable_v different in GCC and MSVC?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, type-traits

When running this simple program, different behaviour is observed depending on the compiler.

It prints `true` when compiled by GCC 11.2, and `false` when compiled by MSVC 19.29.30137 with the (both are the latest release as of today).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    int a;
    
    S()                     = delete;
    S(S const &)            = delete;
    S(S &&)                 = delete;
    S &operator=(S const &) = delete;
    S &operator=(S &&)      = delete;
    ~S()                    = delete;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable_v<S>;
}
```

Relevant quotes (from the latest C++23 working draft [N4901](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4901.pdf)):

Given 20.15.5.4 [meta.unary.prop], `std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>` is defined to be true if T is a `trivially copyable type` as defined at 6.8.1/9 [basic.types.general]:

> Arithmetic types (6.8.2), enumeration types, pointer types, pointer-to-member types (6.8.3), std::nullptr_t,
> and cv-qualified (6.8.4) versions of these types are collectively called scalar types. Scalar types, trivially
> copyable class types (11.2), arrays of such types, and cv-qualified versions of these types are collectively called
> trivially copyable types.

where `trivially copyable class types` is defined at 11.2/1 [class.prop]:

> 1 A trivially copyable class is a class:

> — that has at least one eligible copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator (11.4.4, 11.4.5.3, 11.4.6),

> — where each eligible copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, and move assignment operator is trivial, and

> — that has a trivial, non-deleted destructor (11.4.7).

Eligible (11.4.4 [special]):

> 1 Default constructors (11.4.5.2), copy constructors, move constructors (11.4.5.3), copy assignment operators,
> move assignment operators (11.4.6), and prospective destructors (11.4.7) are special member functions.
>
> 6 An eligible special member function is a special member function for which:

> — the function is not deleted,

> — the associated constraints (13.5), if any, are satisfied, and

> — no special member function of the same kind is more constrained

`trivial` for these functions (as defined at 11.4.5.3/11 [class.copy.ctor], 11.4.6/9 [class.copy.assign], 11.4.7/8 [class.dtor]) generally means:

> - the function is not user-provided.
> - there's nothing virtual to the class
> - each non-static data member has the relevant trivial function

As per 9.5.2/5 [dcl.fct.def.default], the deleted functions in the provided program aren't user-provided:

> ... A function is user-provided if it is user-declared
> and not explicitly defaulted or deleted on its first declaration. ...

If my understanding is correct, `struct S` has `deleted` `special member functions` making them non-`eligible`, which doesn't meet the requirements for a `trivially copyable class type` and `trivially copyable type`. Therefore the conforming behaviour is MSVC's. Is this correct?

Comment: Well, at the same time you are posting here, you could post your findings to the g++ team and have them look at it.

Comment: [Compiler comparison](https://godbolt.org/z/E5991dM9h) for reference. Both GCC and Clang treat `S` as trivally copyable for C++17 and later, but not for C++14 and below.

Comment: Yes, make sure you have chosen the C++17 flag when you compiled with Visual Studio.  The default for a project using that compiler is C++14.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie FWIW, MSVC considers `S` to not be trivially copyable even with `/std:c++17` or `/std:c++20`.

Comment: Do those compilers support C++23 yet?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96288 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98936 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1734

Comment: @JeffGarrett why don't you extract relevant info from defect and post as an answer?

Comment: @SergeyA, time. :) I've posted one now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GCC and Clang report that [`S` is trivially copyable](https://godbolt.org/z/PsfYh6TGK) in C++11 through C++23 standard modes. MSVC reports that [`S` is not trivially copyable](https://godbolt.org/z/b91Y6E8sP) in C++14 through C++20 standard modes.

[N3337](https://wg21.link/std11) (~ C++11) and [N4140](https://wg21.link/std14) (~ C++14) say:

> A trivially copyable class is a class that:
>
> - has no non-trivial copy constructors,
> - has no non-trivial move constructors,
> - has no non-trivial copy assignment operators,
> - has no non-trivial move assignment operators, and
> - has a trivial destructor.

By this definition, `S` **is** trivially copyable.

[N4659](https://wg21.link/std17) (~ C++17) says:

> A trivially copyable class is a class:
>
> - where each copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, and move assignment
>   operator is either deleted or trivial,
> - that has at least one non-deleted copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or
>   move assignment operator, and
> - that has a trivial, non-deleted destructor

By this definition, `S` is **not** trivially copyable.

[N4860](https://wg21.link/std20) (~ C++20) says:

> A trivially copyable class is a class:
>
> - that has at least one eligible copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move
>   assignment operator,
> - where each eligible copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, and move assignment
>   operator is trivial, and
> - that has a trivial, non-deleted destructor.

By this definition, `S` is **not** trivially copyable.

Thus, as published, `S` was trivally copyable in C++11 and C++14, but not in C++17 and C++20.

The change was adopted from [DR 1734](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1734) in February 2016. Implementors generally treat DRs as though they apply to all prior language standards by convention. Thus, by the published standard for C++11 and C++14, `S` was trivially copyable, and by convention, newer compiler versions might choose to treat `S` as not trivially copyable in C++11 and C++14 modes.  Thus, all compilers could be said to be correct for C++11 and C++14.

For C++17 and beyond, `S` is unambiguously not trivially copyable so GCC and Clang are incorrect. This is [GCC bug #96288](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96288) and [LLVM bug #39050](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39050)